SQS triggered Lambda not going to Destination
I have an AWS Lambda function which uses SQS as a trigger.

After the lambda completes, I want to send data to another SQS indicating a success and or failure.
To accomplish this I have added 2 Destinations, both for the same queue one OnFailure and the other OnSuccess.

I have verified my Lambda policy has access to all sqs resources as well as all sqs actions.
To test I am sending data to one of my Trigger SQS queues and not using the Lambda Test feature. I've read the Test console prevents Destinations from being hit.
However, the destination SQS queue is never populated.
What could be preventing my Lambda from triggering the Destination?

Does this answer your question? AWS Lambda w/ SQS trigger, SQS Lambda Destinations, never adds to destination queue

Unfortunately I think it does, so when triggering a lambda from an SQS queue it is going to be synchronous and will never trigger destinations?

That's correct.  See Configuring destinations for event source mapping invocations in the Lambda docs.  Kinesis, DynamoDB and Kafka event sources only.  Not SQS.
